# rm except last 5 files bash

Tags: bash, xargs, rm

I found 5 last  core files.

I need to delete all core files except these 5 files.

```
ls -t /u01/1/bin/core.siebprocmw.* |head -n 5
```

command to find 5 last files by time.

```
ls -t /u01/1/bin/core.siebprocmw.* |head -n 5 |xargs rm -r
```

command remove found last 5 files.

I need to delete all files except these last 5 files. Any ideas?

Comment: use `find` together with `-exec` and a suitable time. `man find` is your friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use sed to exclude the first five newest files, then delete the rest:

```
ls -t /u01/1/bin/core.siebprocmw.* | sed '1,5d' | xargs rm -r
```

Comment: It prints every line except the range line 1 through 5. The 'd' is the sed command for delete.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try

```
ls -t /u01/1/bin/core.siebprocmw.* | head -n -5 | xargs rm -r
```

head -n -5 selects everything except the last 5 lines in the output of ls.